# Android Device Monitor doesn't open - error on log file

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, ddms

In Android Studio when I try running Android Device Monitor, I get the following error on log file:

> ```
>     >!SESSION 2014-12-17 09:57:30.625 -----------------------------------------------
>     eclipse.buildId=unknown
>     java.version=1.8.0_25
>     java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>     BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_BR
>     Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault
>
>     >!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-17 09:57:31.366
>     !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.
>
>     >!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-17 09:57:31.372
>     !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4
> ```
>
> not found.
>
> ```
>     >!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-17 09:57:31.373
>     !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not
> ```
>
> found.
>
> ```
>     >!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-17 09:57:31.439
>     !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not
> ```
>
> found.
>
> ```
>     >!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-17 09:57:31.439
>     !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not
> ```
>
> found.
>
> ```
>     >!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-17 09:57:31.440
>     !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4
> ```
>
> not found.
>
> ```
> ...
>
>     >!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-17 09:57:32.218
>     !MESSAGE Application error
>     !STACK 1
>     >java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\SAA%20PC\.android\monitor-workspace\.metadata" is read-only.
>     > at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.lock(BasicLocation.java:206)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:164)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:137)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:53)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
> ```

Anyone know what could it be? Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you are on windows try opening your Android Studio in **Administrative Mode** *(Run as administrator)*

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Can you explain what was the cause of the problem?

Comment: @LuciusHipan Administative Mode elevates the process to access and writes on `/AppData`. From the log it seemed that the process wanted to change data on the `/Users` folder but couldn't able to because of right privilege.

Comment: @IronBlossom i have installed sdk in d drive and i dont think that it needs any other permission ,although this answer solved my problem

Comment: Is there any way to do this without running as an admin?

Comment: @IronBlossom I am using android studio in linux, what should i do for it.

Comment: @Naitik Try opening Android Device Monitor from the sdk with gksu or gksudo cmd.

Comment: Awesome, I was trying to start it from the command line and opening the command prompt as admin fixed it!

Answer (score 39):

I encounter this problem before. I fixed this issue by killing or ending "monitior.exe" running process using Taskmanager in Windows. Then click ADM (Android Device Monitor) and it works

Comment: Definitely should be the accepted answer...fixed on mac too just force quit the monitor process

Comment: Yep!  I had a bunch of these running (because I like to pound on things to get them to work - haha).  Killed all of them and then back to VS to "Open Android Device Monitor (DDMS)" in the Android Toolbar.  Voila!

Comment: Fixes problem on Win7 + VS 2017

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  This solves multiple problems - unable to start ADM,  no debuggable processes...

Answer (score 9):

This is due to the error that the android device monitor not able to locate the **jre** so in order to solve this :

please follow the following Steps:

**Step 1** : In your android studio find the jdk path, then inside jdk locate the jre and copy it. (In case of Linux  jre is located inside android studio folder)

**Step 2** : After copying **jre** paste it inside the (Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/) i.e monitor-x86_64 directory

I tried this for linux operating system, Android device monitor started well without any error.

Thanks, Hope this will help to someone!

Comment: This answer worked for me with Android Studio 3.0.1, Why this is happening, Is it because of my environmental Variables?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with Mac OS X.

To solve it:

- Open a terminal window
- Navigate to your SDK
- Locate the 'tools' folder
- cd into it
- run: sudo ./monitor
- Type in your password

Good to go!

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem due to updating SDK tools **Android SDK Tools**

- close the **Android Studio**
- open the **SDK Manager.exe** from SDK folder
- Now install **Android SDK tool** in my case tool is Rev.24.3.2
- open **Android Studio** it will show new tool is available install it,install that one and try to restart it.

Answer (score 2):

No need to restart android-studio. Just do this:

1. Navigate to ***C:\Android\sdk\tools***.
2. Find **monitor.bat**
3. Right-click and **Run as administrator**

Comment: very nice answer brother.you save my day

Answer (score 2):

I used jdk-12 in Windows-10 platform, and kinda faced the same problem. This is what I did:

1. Changed the *monitor.exe* file's compatibility to "Run as Administrator"-- Didn't work
2. Checked if the java path (JAVA_HOME and PATH) variables are set, in the [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/environment-variables). --Didn't work
3. Finally uninstalled jdk-12 and installed jdk-8 and altered the path (JAVA_HOME and PATH) variables in [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/environment-variables). -- Worked!!!!! And then the [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI64GG9M2B4wIVR4qPCh389gQ8EAAYASAAEgJlEvD_BwE) opened without any error.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In my case, I use OpenJDK 14 and it's not working. But after I installed Oracle JDK 8, it's working!

Comment: It help for me. Thank you. I used jdk-11. Reinstall at JDK8 and it work

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to restart android Studio only you need to open cmd as administrator and navigate to you SDK tools directory and write monitor
in my case 
C:\Android\sdk\tools\monitor

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Answers as short as this can be posted in the comments section

Comment: @cdomination: I disagree. If it is genuinely a new answer, it should be posted as an answer. "shortness" isn't an issue, though "completeness" often is (many "short" answers don't give enough detail. Not the case here - it truly is that simply.)  Benefits: 1) Not buried in comments. 2) If it works for other people, they can vote it up. 3) If it needs improving, it can be improved or commented on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Android Studio 2.3.1 running on Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I was using openjdk 7. I updated it to openjdk 8 and viola! problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for Xamarin;**

Solution is same as answer from Aman Kumar Gupta. What causes problem is;

Normally as standard Xamarin installs Android Sdk on this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`
But this path is not accepted by Android Studio because of space within the path. So I had to chance the path to be like `C:\Android\android-sdk` after this Android Studio and Visual Studio shares the same path. But all of a sudden Android Device Monitor stopped working. Because as Aman Kumar Gupta said `Jre` location wasn't recognized somehow. You can just copy the jre folder from jdk folder and paste into the `Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/`. This should solve the problem

Comment: you can find jre inside jdk 8: in my case C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot

Comment: @Suchith yea that works as well

Comment: This worked for me!