# I can't open Android Device Monitor

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio. I can't open Android Device Monitor, Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor. I occurred an error. See the log file at:

`C:\Users\Peter Phyo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86\configuration\1433318221838.log.`

Comment: And... what's in the log file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Device Monitor doesn't open - error on log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526596/android-device-monitor-doesnt-open-error-on-log-file)

Comment: I got like that error and I installed Java8 and the problem was resolved for me.

Answer (score 6):

Run android studio as administrator. It will definitely work. No need to reinstall neither android studio nor java.

Comment: I have this issue using ubuntu

Comment: I have same issue with Visual Studio 2017. Just restart the VS 2017 with administrator and run the Android Device Monitor...

Answer (score 5):

Do you have JAVA_HOME in your system environment variables?

```
JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11
```

Comment: Yes. I have JAVA_HOME

Comment: In my case, set JAVA_HOME to jdk8 is not enough, the `PATH` must be updated also, `set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, after upgrading Android Studio 3.1.2, I tried open `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\monitor`, Windows alert "can't find 'lib\monitor-location'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again". Then I tried open `tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor`, it works!

Comment: For some reason I had a problem running it (registry perhaps). Had to download JRE from : https://filehippo.com/search?q=jre . Now it works fine when opening the file that you've provided.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Windows and open Android Studio in **Administrative Mode** *(Run as administrator)*. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i solved it using jPortable, if you're using Windows then take this one, there are two versions 32bits and 64bits : https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable 
 I changed the location for the extraction from `C:\SDK\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\CommonFiles\Java64` to `C:\SDK\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\jre` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set path to your ..jre\bin location :

1. Check in:  File > Project Structure  your JDK location
2. add the \bin there , my path is : `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin`
3. set the path in your Environment Variables, for WINDOWS 7 :

   - the From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
   - Choose Properties from the context menu.
   - Click the Advanced system settings link.
   - Click Environment Variables
   - New System Variable
   - set the path the following way :

`Variable name:  Path`

`Variable value: your path`

in my case: `Variable value: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin`

Now you can start the `Monitor.exe`, my location is here : `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64`

for WIN7 32bit start the `Monitor.exe` from 
`...Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure have installed JDK7 or JDK8 depending on your OS bits
If you are using 32bits your install JDK7 or 8 of 32bits
After you install JDK, your JAVA_HOME in your system will be located in

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
```

To check if your JAVA_HOME is set, CLICK **Start Menu** > **Computer** > **Right Click on Computer** > **Properties** > Control Panel Home will appear, > click **Advanced System Settings**, under > **Advanced Tab** click > **Environment Variables** and check on the > **System Variables** for > **Path** if Java [`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;`] is there, than you are good to go.

Make sure you have your JAVA_HOME in your system environment variables.

Hope this well help you. If it helped you, please mark it, so that it can the useful to others.

Comment: Yes! I am using Windows-7 32 bits. I can't open ADM even set JAVA_HOME, **(C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40)** An Monitor error dialog box showed.

Comment: Do you have jdk1.8.0_40 32bits installed on your PC?

Comment: Can you install it, but if you have it uninstall it and install it again and see what changes it met bring to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have `Android SDK Tools` installed. 
I had a fresh copy of Android Studio and kept getting this error.

To install:

> **Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (tab) -> Tick Android SDK Tools x.x.x (if it's not installed) -> Apply**

Once installed / finished, try restarting Android Studio then selecting Android Device Monitor from the Tools drop down again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see file explorer the please go from this path

View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer.

I hope this path solve your problem.