# When i open Android Device Monitor accur Error

Tags: android

[image]

This is the error when I open my Android device monitor to see my log files 
and the Android device monitor is not opening.
Is there anyone who can help me  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows try opening your Android Studio in Administrative Mode (Run as administrator) or you can goto your sdk/tools/ then right click on exe file and select run as administrator.
[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526596/android-device-monitor-doesnt-open-error-on-log-file)