# Android device monitor is not loading in android studio

Tags: android, android-device-monitor

My device configured with :
 mac Sierra 10.12.6,
 Android studio 2.3.3, 
 java 8. 
Android device monitor shows 'an error has occurred' and generated a log report.

Here is the few lines log report:I cant understand the issue with device monitor. How to resolve this issue?

```
!SESSION 2017-11-30 09:45:22.279 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/sarathvijayaraghavan/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault -keyring /Users/sarathvijayaraghavan/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-30 09:45:23.746
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-30 09:45:23.751
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-30 09:45:23.752
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-30 09:45:23.822
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-30 09:45:23.822
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-30 09:45:23.823
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-30 09:45:23.824
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-30 09:45:23.828
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526596/android-device-monitor-doesnt-open-error-on-log-file) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661578/android-device-monitor-will-not-launch-either-from-android-studio-or-from-termi/42704939)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried above mentioned method by @ArnoldBrown and some other solutions from similar questions.But those wont works for me.
 I just updated JDK and JRE with latest version. Problem solved after updation and restart . Don't know it is the exact solution or not.

Java reference link : 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Thanks everyone for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

**Windows**

**If this due to privilege**

Administative Mode elevates the process to access and writes on */AppData*. From the log it seemed that the process wanted to change data on the */Users* folder but couldn't able to because of right privilege.

Try opening your Android Studio in **Administrative Mode** (Run as administrator)

**If due to updating SDK tools - Android SDK Tools**

- close the Android Studio
- open the SDK Manager.exe from SDK folder
- Now install Android SDK tool in my case tool is Rev.24.3.2
- open Android Studio it will show new tool is available install
  it,install that
- one and try to restart it.

**Mac OS X**

- Open a terminal window
- Navigate to your SDK
- Locate the 'tools' folder
- cd into it
- run: sudo ./monitor
- Type in your password

Comment: This one not works for me, but works for my friend in windows . I just updated JDK and JRE with latest version. Problem solved for me after updation and restart . Don't know it is the exact solution or not. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply with the solution you got. +1 for your answer it may help someone.