# ADB (Android Debug Bridge) error Java debug

Tags: java, android, adb

I'm using `ADB` (Android Debug Bridge) for a couple of months and for a week or 2 without any abnormal usage or files modified I encounter the following problem with an error log that i can't seem to find any solution

I've attached the 2 logs here maybe can someone give me or point me in the right direction : https://ufile.io/d86re

On another forum the only solution suggested is to have a complete OS reinstall which is not an option for me.

The following solutions were tried :
- Full complete reinstall of `ADB`
- Re-create the path to `ADB`
- Re-installed `Java` SE Development Kit 8 and 9

~~~ EDIT TRUNK TEXT ~~~

```
 !STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025 [46]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.common 4 0 2017-12-19 16:06:23.645
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
```

Nothing seems to work.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you inline those logs (maybe truncate them a bit so they don't bloat the question) so we don't have to download stuff from unknown sources?

Comment: see this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse.

Comment: Something like this ?

!SESSION 2017-12-18 12:42:26.388 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-18 12:42:26.792
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526596/android-device-monitor-doesnt-open-error-on-log-file

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH , tried all variants on both link,same issue, samer error log

Comment: Have you updated the JRE or JVM on your PC recently? If so, try to update your Eclipse as well

Comment: @DmitryArc i already have all things up to date, nothing can be updated more.